# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model “Post”

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My `./models/models.js` is as follows

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String, //hash created from password
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    created_by: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    text: String
});

mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I am invoking it in api.js as

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
```

this is my app.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                         //add for Mongo support
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testchirp'); 
require('./models/models');

var app = express();
```

When I run the application, I got an error 
[image]

Where I am doing mistake, I unable to find that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
```

What i am not getting is your `api.js` file?
From your error code, i see that its a `route` file. Where is your `route` file included? Is it above `Mongodb` dependencies or below?

**This error is related on where your routes are included.**

Comment: I am adding routes above the Mongodb connection and dependencies. so the formation is matter?